# How to use lambda expression to access correct data type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using lambda expression to access values with data type, but the problem I have data type for Time as Time(7) on my local database and using Entity Framework. On my model this data type is define as `DateTime`.

How do I now access this data type to be time?

This is my code:

```
public List GetIncident_Details()
{
    Entities incident = new Entities();
    List result = new List();

    var c_incident = incident.Incident_Template.Select(c => c).ToList();

    if (c_incident != null && c_incident.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var cData in c_incident)
        {
            Incident_DropDown model = new Incident_DropDown();
            model.Title = cData.Title;
            model.Description = cData.Description;
            model.Date_Occurred = cData.Date_Occurred;

            // How do I change this to have access? 
            // It's complaining about the data type object being set to a string?
            model.Time = cData.Time; 
            model.Assignment_Group = cData.Assignment_Group;
            model.Reported_CI = cData.Reported_CI;

            result.Add(model);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public class Incident_DropDown
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Date_Occurred { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; } // Time
    public string Assignment_Group { get; set; }
    public string Reported_CI { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `TimeSpan` instead if `DateTime`?

Comment: @AlexyRumnyantsev no havent

Answer (score 1):

Took some advice from @alexey-rumyantsev, then had to test my code by interrogating model data  type for Time it was Date Time, then change to Timespan. While testing this data type compare to my local database record and it was passing correct vales when debugging.
// Model name

```
public class Incident_DropDown
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }


        public string Description { get; set; }


        public string Date_Occured { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan Time { get; set; } // had to change to work

        public string Assignment_Group { get; set; }


        public string Reported_CI { get; set; }

    }

// Controller
   public List<Incident_DropDown> GetIncident_Details()
        {
            Entities incident = new Entities();
            List<Incident_DropDown> result = new List<Incident_DropDown>();


            var c_incident = incident.Incident_Template.Select(c => c).ToList();
            if (c_incident != null && c_incident.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var cData in c_incident)
                {
                    Incident_DropDown model = new Incident_DropDown();
                    model.Title = cData.Title;
                    model.Description = cData.Description;
                    model.Date_Occured = cData.Date_Occured;
                    model.Time = cData.Time; // This here enable to pass correct time as per database record
                    model.Assignment_Group = cData.Assignment_Group;
                    model.Reported_CI = cData.Reported_CI;


                    result.Add(model);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```